# Способ проверки установленного JVM при запуске exe файла java программы

Tags: java, swing, javafx, exe, export

Всем привет!
Имеется готовое приложение на Java, которое было экспортировано в exe файл.

Необходимо сделать проверку при запуске программы на наличие установленной Java (как это реализовано при запуске Eclipse).

Т.е мы запускаем программу (например, двойным кликом мыши)---> программа проверяет наличие установленной JVM ---> если JVM установлена, то программа просто запускается, если не установлена, то выводит диалоговое окно с ошибкой, о том, что надо установить Java.

Никто не подскажет, как реализовать такую конструкцию?)

Comment: чем "экспортировали"?

Comment: @zRrr, по этому методу [ссылка](http://ru.wikihow.com/создать-исполняемый-файл-в-Eclipse)

Comment: Все, разобрался, в утилите, через которую получаю exe есть такая настройка